# Finding string in the format of TEXT-###, e.g SFS-444 inside of another string

Tags: python, string, subset

Pretty much as the statement states, I'm trying to figure out how to find text that follows this format TEXT-### inside of another string. However, there may be a lot of words or multiple numbers, such as,

```
FRS-44215
SLMP-44
AG-1
```

So for example I have this text.

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adversarium suscipiantur 
has ea, duo at alia assum, eu ius hinc 
aliquip percipitur SGF-7852 Nec ne 
nisl duis volutpat"
```

The code would pick out `SGF-7852`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to define the pattern that you are looking for, and then search the string for it.

```
>>> s = '''"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adversarium suscipiantur 
... has ea, duo at alia assum, eu ius hinc 
... aliquip percipitur SGF-7852 Nec ne 
... nisl duis volutpat"'''
>>> e = r'[A-Z]+-\d+'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(e, s)
['SGF-7852']
```

Here the pattern is:

- `[A-Z]+` (one or more capital letters)
- `-` followed by a dash
- `\d+` followed by one or more numbers

Comment: Wow, that's kind of amazing, does exactly what I need, thank you!